# Error 18456 Login failed for User

Tags: sql-server-2012, logins

We are observing these below errors in our logs frequently and it gets fixed automatically -

Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 46. Login failed for user 'sqllogin'. Reason: Failed to open the database 'DBNAME' configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: Ipaddress]

The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID ***, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.

What is the cause of this,why this is occuring.
We can see multiple active sessions and long running selects at the same time.

Note - This brings the production down.

Comment: Do you recognize the IP Address and which machine it may belong to? Why do you think this brings production down?

Comment: Is AUTO_CLOSE turned on for the database?

Comment: @HandyD Yes this is turned Off.

Comment: Yes the ip address belongs to the Application Servers. There are more than 1000+ active sessions and selects running more than 15 seconds. And there are async network io wait types. @J.D.

Comment: @Mrigank None of those should be caused by the error you mentioned. If anything, the error you're running into is happening because of how many active sessions you have and you're running into an issue like thread exhaustion perhaps (though I don't think 1,000 active sessions should be an issue by itself either). In any case, you should add your server's hardware configuration and maybe adding the output of [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) when the issue occurs, to your post, would help pinpoint the source of your issue.